# serialize an interface wcf

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have an interface, called IDeviceConfig, as follows:

```
[KnownType(typeof(Device))]
[KnownType(typeof(DeviceGroup))]
[DataContract()]
public interface IDeviceConfig
{
    [DataMember()]
    string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    List<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    ActionResult PerformAction(string ActionId);
}
```

The interface will be implemented by two classes, as follows:

```
public class Device : IDeviceConfig
{
...
}

public class DeviceGroup : IDeviceConfig
{
...
}
```

In my WCF service, I need to return a list of IDeviceConfigs; when I decorate the interface with `KnownType`, Visual studio complains saying that Attribute 'KnownType' is not valid on this declaration type.

Can someone please explain how to return a list of IDeviceconfigs?

Comment: Are `Device` and `DeviceGroup` services or data contracts?  It looks like you're mixing up a couple of things.

Comment: Device and Device Groups are data contracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `KnownTypeAttribute`, you cannot apply to Interfaces.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class KnownTypeAttribute : Attribute
```

"Known types can be associated only with classes and structures, not interfaces." from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx